# Propositional language has an independent set of axioms

Tags: logic

Let $\mathcal{L}_0$ be the language consisting of all propositional symbols $A_n$, along with all formulas formed by using $\neg$ and $\to$.  In other words, it is the smallest set $L$ such that $A_n \in L$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and if $\varphi,\psi \in L$ then $(\neg \varphi), (\varphi \to \psi) \in L$.

Show that, for any set $\Gamma \subseteq \mathcal{L}_0$, there exists an independent set $\Delta$ which is logically equivalent to $\Gamma$.

I am not interested in the case where $\Gamma$ is finite.  It is easy to show, in this case, not only that $\Delta$ exists but that $\Delta$ is actually a subset of $\Gamma$.  Here, $\Gamma$ is not finite but it IS countable (you can show actually that $\mathcal{L}_0$ is countable, so of course $\Gamma \subseteq \mathcal{L}_0$ is countable).

A very similar question has already been asked here:

[Proving that a propositional theory of any cardinality has an independent set of axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913680/proving-that-a-propositional-theory-of-any-cardinality-has-an-independent-set-of).

However, the solution posted (given in the third paragraph of the question) seems completely flawed to me.  I've tried several approaches but I've found nothing.  I would have thought that this would be a well-known exercise, but I haven't found it discussed anywhere online except for in this one link I've given above.

Comment: Please, can you be more explicit about the point of the referred post that is not correct, according to you ?

Comment: In the third paragraph, the author begins using $\sigma_i$.  I assume the $\sigma_i$ are the consequences of $\Gamma$.  They could also be the elements of $\Gamma$.  In either case, it is completely possible that $\sigma_0$, for instance, is a tautology.  Then in his argument, $\delta_0 = \psi_0 = \sigma_0$ could be a tautology, thus his set $\Delta$ is definitely not independent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution, but I'd appreciate if anyone could check it to make sure I'm not crazy:

Let $\Phi$ be the set of all consequences of $\Gamma$.  Since $\Phi \subseteq \mathcal{L}_0$, we know that $\Phi$ is countable.  So $\Phi$ = $\{ \varphi_i \}_{i=0}^\infty$.

Define a sequence $\{ \Delta_n \}$ as follows: If $\{ \varphi_0 \}$ is independent, let $\Delta_0 = \{ \varphi_0 \}$.  Otherwise, let $\Delta_0 = \emptyset$.  Next, for $n>0$, if $\Delta_{n-1} \cup \{\varphi_n \}$ is independent, let $\Delta_n = \Delta_{n-1} \cup \{\varphi_n \}$.  Otherwise, if $\Delta_{n-1}$ is logically equivalent to $\Delta_{n-1} \cup \{\varphi_n \}$, then let $\Delta_n = \Delta_{n-1}$.  Otherwise, let $$\Delta_n = \Delta_{n-1} \cup \left \{ \left( \left( \bigwedge_{i=0}^{n-1} \varphi_i \right) \to \varphi_n \right) \right \}.$$

Finally, let $$\Delta = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty \Delta_i.$$  I believe $\Delta$ is now independent and logically equivalent to $\Gamma$.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on how your $\Delta$ is equivalent to $\Gamma$?